# Once in a while Chrome does render a page without stylesheets for couple of seconds

Tags: css, google-chrome, stylesheet

This seems rather a common problem, however I can't find any reliable sources on this.

Once in a while Chrome will display a stylesheet-less version of page for like 2-3 seconds and soon after the page is displayed correctly. It can affect the very same page once in every 20-50 refresh and its not tied to a specific site. Happens all over the place. There are some threads about this [here and there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967469/in-which-case-webpage-loads-without-external-stylesheet-in-chrome-or-safari), but I have yet to find a full explanation.

Is this a bug? Feature? Is there a way to prevent Chrome from behaving like this on the client or perhaps server side?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, this happens when the network connection is poor and the page is (necessarily) loading slowly.  The page's HTML will render first, and other assets called for within that HTML (like stylesheets or images) are rendered only after their calls are complete and their respective files load.

Comment: Did you empty your cache, etc. before trying to replicate this?  I find it happens most often with sites I'm visiting for the first time (it just happened to me a minute ago, in fact--in Firefox, on a site I had never loaded before).

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this as well. It's definitely a bug. It seems to be this issue:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=75761

You can "force" the stylesheet to load by opening the inspector (ctrl+shift+i).

Answer (score 0):

shift + f5 should reload the page *and the referenced stylesheets*

With a normal reload it will only reload the page itself, and incorrectly assume that the stylesheets in the cache (the ones that never loaded in the first place) are correct.